DateTimeParseException when parsing 01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC, where is the issue?
I have the following Java (version 8) code that parses a date time string that looks like '01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC'. Expected result is a ZonedDateTime of 2025-02-01T00:00Z[UTC]. But I keep getting the error "java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC' could not be parsed at index 3".
Minimal code to reproduce:
    String dateTimeInput = "01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC";
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInput, inputFormatter);

I also tried the below input formatter using DateTimeFormatterBuilder instead, but it still can't parse the input string.
This time the exception message mentions a different index:

Text '01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC' could not be parsed at index 32

    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z")
            .optionalStart()
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
            .optionalEnd()
            .appendPattern(" a z") // AM/PM and time zone
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

Can anyone spot the issue in my code and can point me in the right direction?
Original code
The full method converts the input date time string to something that the Oracle SQL database can understand:
private String convertDateTime(String dateTimeInput) {
        if (csDateTime != null) {
            try {
                // Incoming date time looks like '01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC'
                DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                // Parse the input string into ZonedDateTime
                ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInput, inputFormatter);

                // Convert to LocalDateTime in UTC
                LocalDateTime dateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();

                return dateTime.format(outputFormatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to parse date: {}", dateTimeInput, e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

Attempt using DateTimeFormatterBuilder:
                DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z")
                        .optionalStart()
                        .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
                        .optionalEnd()
                        .appendPattern(" a z") // AM/PM and time zone
                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
                DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInput, inputFormatter);
                LocalDateTime dateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();
                return dateTime.format(outputFormatter);


Not quite sure why your optionals are present, as DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z").toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH); seems to fit with what you have, and works. I'm also a little puzzled about why you're entering datetime values as strings into a database ...

UTC is generally regarded as 24 hour tine, input as 24 hour. (get rid of the AM and use 24 hour)

Also, to be complete, i should said, UTC is (read) the same time in any zone around the world ( hence "Time Constant" ! ) only local national "zone" time can truly be expressed as AM or PM.

@SamuelMarchant That‘s new to me, and I am sceptical about it. In any case it seems to me that the OP is getting a string in UTC with 12 hour clock from somewhere, and if they can‘t get a better string from that somewhere, they can obviously parse it as it is.

Your second attempt using .parseCaseInsensitive() works when you get rid of the redundant .SSSSSS a z.

Where are you getting that string from? Also asking because it might look to me like something from an Oracle database that should have been retrieved as OffsetDateTime rather than as String. Also as @g00se already said, you should store a proper date-time object back into your database (depending on database data type for example LocalDateTime, OffsetDateTime orLocalDate).

Your first solution is not working because the date time formatted is case sensitive so FEB is not accepted but Feb would work
the second solution is not working because you have added a lot of unnecessary configuration in the case the expected string should be something like 01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC.000000 AM UTC
here is an example of working code:
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "01-FEB-25 12.00.00.000000 AM UTC";
        System.out.println(convertDateTime(input));
    }

    private static String convertDateTime(String dateTimeInput) {

            try {
                DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z")
                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
                DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                // Parse the input string into ZonedDateTime
                ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeInput, inputFormatter);

                // Convert to LocalDateTime in UTC
                LocalDateTime dateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime();

                return dateTime.format(outputFormatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
    }
}


Looks like this will do the trick:
private String convertDateTime(String input) {
        if (csDateTime != null) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a z");
                formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                Date parsedDate = formatter.parse(input);
                return new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime()).toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to parse date: {}", input, e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


No! That old date package should no longer be used

"Never mind your actual question I will prove completely different code that seems to do what you want without any explanation and using obsolete classes with many known problems" - this isn't a good way to answer SO questions.

This should have more inline with what user is asking or what is that mistake which the user is doing.
